# What can not be done / which results are impossible to show using SQL?

Tags: sql

I would like to know if there is any problem or any sort of combinations that can not be solved using SQL language.

Is there any list in the web where I can find situations that are impossible to measure using SQL?

Or is everything possible to calculate using SQL.

Thank you.

Comment: This question is unclear, can you provide some examples of limitations you'd expect it to have? Obviously SQL cannot make you a cup of coffee out of the box (but you could wire a USB port up to a coffee machine and get SQL to call out to an exe via command line which would start the coffee brewing...), clarification needed

Comment: Like most languages, SQL is [Turing complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). There is nothing you can't do in SQL :)

Answer (score 1):

SQL is pretty flexible, but it can't do everything. However there is no handy guide that I know of that lists what it can't do. There are things that I think you can do but shouldn't: anything that involves doing calculations one row at a time are very inefficient and will generally be faster if done in code.